# Shebang line #!/usr/bin/python3 preventing server run

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, line, shebang

Here's the code I have. Basically I have the Shebang line in there because the psycopg2 wasn't working without it.

But now when I have this line in there it doesn't allow me to run the database, it just says "no module named 'flask'"

```
 #!/usr/bin/python3.4
    #
    # Small script to show PostgreSQL and Pyscopg together
    #

    from flask import Flask, render_template
    from flask import request
    from flask import *
    from datetime import datetime
    from functools import wraps
    import time
    import csv
    import psycopg2
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.secret_key ='lukey'
    def getConn():
        connStr=("dbname='test' user='lukey' password='lukey'")
        conn=psycopg2.connect(connStr)
        return conn

    @app.route('/')
    def home():
        return render_template(index.html)

    @app.route('/displayStudent', methods =['GET'])
    def displayStudent():
        residence = request.args['residence']
        try:
            conn = None
            conn = getConn()
            cur = conn.cursor()
            cur.execute('SET search_path to public')

            cur.execute('SELECT stu_id,student.name,course.name,home_town FROM student,\
                        course WHERE course = course_id AND student.residence = %s',[residence])
            rows = cur.fetchall()
            if rows:
                return render_template('stu.html', rows = rows, residence = residence)
            else:
                return render_template('index.html', msg1='no data found')

        except Exception as e:
            return render_template('index.html', msg1='No data found', error1 = e)

        finally:
            if conn:
                conn.close()

    #@app.route('/addStudent, methods =['GET','POST']')
    #def addStudent():

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug = True)
```

Comment: The shebang makes the code run with the system version of python. If flask is not installed system-wide (as in the case it was installed with virtualenv, of for python2), the package will not be found. Have you installed the flask package with pip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an environment problem, not a flask, postgres or shebang problem. A specific version of Python is being called, and it is not being given the correct path to its libraries.

Depending on what platform you are on, changing you shebang to `#! /usr/bin/env python3` can fix the problem, but if not (very likely not, though using `env` is considered better/portable practice these days), then you may need to add your Python3 libs location manually in your code.

```
sys.path.append("/path/to/your/python/libs")
```

If you know where your Python libs are (or maybe flask is installed somewhere peculiar?) then you can add that to the path and imports following the line where you added to the path will include it in their search for modules.

Comment: I tried using #! /usr/bin/env python3 I still get the same error about the module flask. My python libs are C:\python27 and C:\python24 ( I downloaded both because I was unsure). This is my environment variables "C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\".  I've tried installing flask 100 different ways

Comment: You are trying to run *python3* but you say you have *python2* installed. Also, I don't know that the shebang has any effect on Windows at all -- likely not (its sort of a unix standard thing). Get in your shell and try `import sys` and then `print(sys.path)` and see what is included. Also, just in case it does have some effect, change the shebang to `#! /usr/bin/env python` (remove the "3"). Try to locate wherever flask is installed -- that is the place you have to include -- but I suspect its that you have flask installed in your python2 libs and not python3.

Comment: In the python34 shell I got "C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\python34.zip,' 'C:\\Python34\\DLLs' , 'C:\\Python34\\ Lib', 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages'" Also when I used #! /usr/bin/env python I got an import error for psycopg2

Comment: It sounds like maybe you have psycopg2 for python3, and flask for python2. Get both flask and psycopg2 for the same python version, and stick with it. Run your script by calling the python executable directly like `c:\python27\python.exe your_script.py` or similar.

Comment: I'm just going to uninstall everything, which versions should I use?

Comment: Don't uninstall everything! NO!!! You've got Python 2.7. I know that flask and psycopg2 work for it. So keep it. You just need to locate the python executable in C:\Python27\ -- it is probably `C:\Python27\python.exe` Try typing that, and see if you get a shell.

Comment: yeah I get a shell. What should I do with it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74936/discussion-between-zxq9-and-user3667111).